# How to connect Cassandra using Java class

Tags: java, cassandra

I am doing this  to connect cassandra.But my code is returning an error.. Here is my code

```
public class CassandraConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String serverIp = "166.78.10.41";
    String keyspace = "gamma";
    CassandraConnection connection;

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(serverIp)
            .build();

    Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);


    String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM TestCF";
    for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
        System.out.println(row.toString());
    }

}
}
```

this is the error log ..

> Failed to execute goal on project CassandraConnection: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:CassandraConnection:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.specs2:scalaz-effect_2.11.0-SNAPSHOT:jar:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT, org.scalaz:scalaz-effect_2.9.3:jar:7.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.specs2:scalaz-effect_2.11.0-SNAPSHOT:jar:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Did you do any research on the matter?

### Picking a driver

You need a way to communicate with cassandra, best option is to use a high level API. You have a wide range of choices here but when we look at it from a high level prespective there are really two choices.

1. **CQL based drivers** - Higher level abstraction of what thrift does. Also the newer tool, companies providing support / documentation for cassandra recommend that new cassandra applications are CQL based.
2. **Thrift based drives** - Have access to low level storage, so its easier to get things wrong.

I'll use [datastax's CQL driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver).

Download and build the driver from datastax's github repo **OR** use maven and add the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Picking maven is a good idea, as it will manage all your dependencies for you, but if you dont use maven, at least you will learn about managing jars and reading through stack-traces.

### Code

The [driver's documentation](http://www.datastax.com/doc-source/developer/java-driver/#quick_start/qsQuickstart_c.html) is coming along nicely. If you get stuck read through it, the documentation contains lots of examples.

I'll use the following two variables throughout the examples.

```
String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
String keyspace = "system";

Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
  .addContactPoints(serverIP)
  .build();

Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

// you are now connected to the cluster, congrats!
```

**Read**

```
String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM local";
for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
  System.out.println(row.toString());
}
```

**Create/Update/Delete**

```
// for all three it works the same way (as a note the 'system' keyspace cant 
// be modified by users so below im using a keyspace name 'exampkeyspace' and
// a table (or columnfamily) called users

String cqlStatementC = "INSERT INTO exampkeyspace.users (username, password) " + 
                      "VALUES ('Serenity', 'fa3dfQefx')";

String cqlStatementU = "UPDATE exampkeyspace.users " +
                      "SET password = 'zzaEcvAf32hla'," +
                      "WHERE username = 'Serenity';";

String cqlStatementD = "DELETE FROM exampkeyspace.users " + 
                      "WHERE username = 'Serenity';";

session.execute(cqlStatementC); // interchangeable, put any of the statements u wish.
```

### Other useful code

**Creating a Keyspace**

```
String cqlStatement = "CREATE KEYSPACE exampkeyspace WITH " + 
  "replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':1}";

session.execute(cqlStatement);
```

**Creating a ColumnFamily (aka table)**

```
// based on the above keyspace, we would change the cluster and session as follows:
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
  .addContactPoints(serverIP)
  .build();
Session session = cluster.connect("exampkeyspace");

String cqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE users (" + 
                      " username varchar PRIMARY KEY," + 
                      " password varchar " + 
                      ");";

session.execute(cqlStatement);
```

Comment: This answer is freaking amazing. I wish I could +1 it about 30 more times.

Answer (score 4):

To connect with cassandra from a java program, you need to add some basic dependency to the program. Add the following dependencies to the program. 
Maven dependencies List:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.20.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Simple java program to connect with cassandra to a keyspace and to retrieve the values of a table

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serverIp = "127.0.0.1";
        String keyspace = "test";

        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(serverIp)
                .build();

        Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);


        String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM emp";
        for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
            System.out.println(row.toString());
        }

        session.close();
    }
}
```

Git Hub Repo for the program as maven project: [GitURL](https://github.com/Vishnu-Prabhakar/cassandraJavaConnect)

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but what this answer adds to already existing one? (from 5 years ago)

Comment: Yea, but the existing answer has only two dependencies mentioned and with those dependencies we wont be able to connect with cassandra. And right dependencies with proper version will connect to the DB. That's why mentioned the required dependencies which works properly with respective to versions also.

Comment: In reality, you only need one dependency - to `cassandra-driver-core`... Guava is dependency of `java-driver-mapping`. And in rare cases you need to use shaded jar: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/shaded_jar/

Comment: When i try to run a program to connect with cassandra, i have included all the mentioned jars to connect successfully. With only cassandra-driver-core and cassandra-driver-mapping I'm getting run time errors to include the other mentioned jars. 
So posted the list of dependencies to connect with cassandra without any errors