# How to use Byte Buffer to serialize a Byte Array to start following Big Endian format?

Tags: java, cassandra, arrays, bytebuffer, endianness

I need to write `Byte Array` value into Cassandra using Java code. Then I will be having my C++ program which will retrieve that Byte Array data from Cassandra and then it will deserialize it.

That Byte Array which I will be writing into Cassandra is made up of three Byte Arrays as described below-

```
short employeeId = 32767;
long lastModifiedDate = "1379811105109L";
byte[] attributeValue = os.toByteArray();
```

Now, I will write `employeeId` , `lastModifiedDate` and `attributeValue` together into a single Byte Array and that resulting Byte Array I will write into Cassandra and then I will be having my C++ program which will retrieve that Byte Array data from Cassandra and then deserialize it to extract `employeeId` , `lastModifiedDate` and `attributeValue` from it.

I am not sure whether I should use Big Endian here in my Java code while writing to Cassandra so that C++ code get simplified while reading it back?

I have given a try on the Java side to make sure it is following certain format (Big Endian) while writing everything into a single Byte Array and then this Byte Array will be written back to Cassandra as well but not sure whether this is right or not?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String os = "Byte Array Test";
    byte[] attributeValue = os.getBytes();

    long lastModifiedDate = 1379811105109L;
    short employeeId = 32767;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOsTest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream outTest = new DataOutputStream(byteOsTest);

    // merging everything into one Byte Array here
    outTest.writeShort(employeeId);
    outTest.writeLong(lastModifiedDate);
    outTest.writeInt(attributeValue.length);
    outTest.write(attributeValue);

    byte[] allWrittenBytesTest = byteOsTest.toByteArray();

    // initially I was writing allWrittenBytesTest into Cassandra...

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(allWrittenBytesTest).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

    // now what value I should write into Cassandra?
    // or does this even looks right?

    // And now how to deserialize it?

}
```

Can anyone help me with this ByteBuffer thing here? Thanks..

I might be mising minute details about Byte Buffer here as this is the first time I am working with it..

1. First of all, should I be using ByteByffer here at all in my use case?
2. Secondly, if yes, then what's the best way to use it within my use case...?

The only thing that I am trying to make sure is, I am writing correctly into Cassandra by following Big-Endians byte order format so that on C++ side, I am not facing any problem at all while deserializing that Byte Array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I never used cassandra, I will only answer in regard to the ByteBuffer part.

You should put everything into the bytebuffer first before sending the bytes, otherwise you cannot control the endianess of what you are storing, and thats exactly the point of using  the ByteBuffer.

To send the bytes use:

```
int size = 2 + 8 + 4 + attributeValue.length; // short is 2 bytes, long 8 and int 4

ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(size); 
bbuf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

bbuf.putShort(employeeId);
bbuf.putLong(lastModifiedDate);
bbuf.putInt(attributeValue.length);
bbuf.put(attributeValue);

bbuf.rewind();

// this is a bad approach because if you modify the returned array
// you are directly modifying the ByteBuffer's internal array.
byte[] bytesToStore = bbuf.array();

// best approach is copy the internal buffer
byte[] bytesToStore = new byte[size];
bbuf.get(bytesToStore);
```

now you can store bytesToStore, sending them to cassandra.

To read them back:

```
byte[] allWrittenBytesTest = magicFunctionToAcquireDataFromCassandra();

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(allWrittenBytesTest);
bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
bb.rewind();

int size = allWrittenBytesTest.length - 14;
short employeeId = bb.getShort();
long lastModifiedDate = bb.getLong();
int attributeValueLen = bb.getInt();
byte[] attributeValue = new byte[size];
bb.get(attributeValue); // read attributeValue from the remaining buffer
```

You don't even need to store the attributeValue length, because the length can be determined again, by subtracting 14 from allWrittenBytesTest.length (being 14 the sum of the other fields size [2 + 4 + 8]).

Edited the code, I had some typos.

Comment: Thanks JoaoHenriques for the suggestion... In your example, can you please tell me how are you calculating the size? And also what does `rewind()` do and what can be the advantage of using it? Thanks for the help..

Comment: I already edited the code to explain how you get the size of the buffer. ByteBuffers have an internal byte pointer, informing which byte to read/write next, doing rewind makes the pointer point to zero [same as bbuf.position(0)]. Every operation you make, increases this pointer by the size consumed by the operation. For example, getInt() reads 4 bytes and increases the pointer by 4. The same goes to putInt(), writes 4 bytes and increases it by 4.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.. Yes, it cleared all my doubts.. One last question that I had is - while deserializing, you are not using `attributeValueLen`  anywhere? Are we supposed to use it somewhere? And you have missed it by mistake? or it is redundant?

Comment: I think, we don't need size in deserialization instead of that we need `attributeValueLen`. Correct me if I am wrong..?

Comment: It really depends on how you are doing it. If you are designing a communication protocol from the ground you need some kind of fixed header size, including the size of the variable data packet part (attributeValueLen) so you can know when to stop reading. But if you  are relying on a library to make that connection for you, that library should (in principle) take care of that in underlying layer of communication.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. It makes sense.. One more thing, in my case, I should be using BIG_ENDIAN or LITTLE_ENDIAN? Any thoughts? or when to use big_endian or little_endian?

Comment: It depends, little endian is the most used byte order by hardware manufactures, but java stores the numeric values in big endian on all jvm implementations. You should store in little endian because most of your clients will be using it. When you retrieve the data from cassandra, in c++ implementation, knowing the byte order you chose to save, you need to test the client's endianess and convert the data to the same byte order if not the same. BTW, big endian is the standard byte order used for network communication.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion... But I get confused now... You said big endian is the standard byte order used for network communication? Right?? In my case what I should be using in general? Bcoz, I will be writing into Cassandra from Java and then reading the same data from Cassandra using C++.. I am guessing that in my case, I should be using BIG ENDIAN? Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of serializing ByteBuffers for Thrift manually, use the native CQL driver for Cassandra: http://github.com/datastax/java-driver

Comment: can you give me an example how to use this with Datastax? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any thoughts on my above question? Thanks

Comment: @TechGeeky check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870502/how-to-connect-cassandra-using-java-class/16871984#16871984) for creating a ks and a cf and inserting / reading from the cf.

Comment: @LyubenTodorov: I know how to insert into Cassandra using Datastax Java driver.. The only thing that I want to understand is why jbellis said we should serialize ByteBuffers manually? I am not sure why he said that.. What we are doing currently is - serialize few fields using Avro schema into byte array and then we are writing those byte array  into Cassandra as a BLOB datatype..

Comment: @TechGeeky Read his comment carefully: **Instead of** serializing ByteBuffers for Thrift manually...

Answer (score 1):

For byte-array endiness doesn't make sense at all. So if casandra doesn't try to interpret your data you can use whether big/little endian. So the encoding makes sense for multi-byte values only.

If you are going to use the data with different clients and probably on different platfroms, I would recommend to take some agreement (use BIG endian for instance) and use same endiness on all of your clients. For instance, java client code would look like this:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(attributeValue.length + 14).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    bb.putShort(employeeId);
    bb.putLong(lastModifiedDate);
    bb.putInt(attributeValue.length);
    bb.put(attributeValue);
```

You have to use ByteBuffer if you are going to use an API which requires it. For instance NIO channels work with ByteBuffers, so if you are going to connect using SocketChannel you can use ByteBuffer.
You can also use ByteBuffer for correctly formatting your multi-byte values. For instance for the code above you can get byte array from the buffer and send it through a socket where 3 first fields packed using big-endian notation:

```
sendByteArray(bb.array());
...
```

Comment: Thanks barmatat for the suggestion.. Yes that's what I was also planning to use BIG endian... Now in your example what value I will be writing back to Cassandra? Should I be writing `bb` to Cassandra? And what does 14 mean here?

Comment: yeh, forgot to say I am not using Cassandra, so don't know their API :(. If it accepts byte-array, you can just get it from your buffer and send directly to Cassandra. 14 is the size of your first 3 fields - short(2) + long(8) + int(4).