# how to setup cassandra java driver with eclipse

Tags: java, cassandra, driver

I am new to cassandra and moven. I was trying to write a simple java program in eclipse that uses cassandra java driver to connect to a cassandra node I have setup.
I found this repository https://github.com/datastax/java-driver but I have no idea what I should do with it. Can anyone give me step by step instructions for getting the driver and creating a simple eclipse project that uses the driver.

Comment: You can get almost everything through Maven Central. It has a search function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Start Eclipse (make sure eclipse has **maven**, I used eclipse KEPLER)
2. Create a new eclipse project (Under the **Maven** folder select "Maven Project")
3. Give the project a name / group-id / artifact-id
4. Open **pom.xml** and then click on the actual pom.xml tab.
5. Add the dependency shown on github, my pom file ended up looking like [this](https://gist.github.com/lyubent/8779559).

And finally write a class to do some stuff with the driver, the below creates a keyspace and a column family.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                          .addContactPoints("127.0.0.1")
                          .build();
        Session session = cluster.connect();
        String cqlStatement = "CREATE KEYSPACE myfirstcassandradb WITH " + 
                              "replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':1}";        
        session.execute(cqlStatement);

        String cqlStatement2 = "CREATE TABLE myfirstcassandradb.users (" + 
                               " user_name varchar PRIMARY KEY," + 
                               " password varchar " + 
                               ");";
        session.execute(cqlStatement2);

        System.out.println("Done");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Also check this answer out for [CRUD operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870502/how-to-connect-cassandra-using-java-class/16871984#16871984) with the driver.

Comment: Thanks Lyuben, it was easier than what I imagined!

Comment: If you please show us how pom.xml will end up like, because attached link not working