# What is the connection URL to be used for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, database-connection, connection-string

What is the connection URL to be used for Cassandra?

jdbc:cassandra:root/root@:/

Comment: What client are you using?  There are cassandra-jdbc adapters out there, but they are all pretty old.

Comment: Hi Andy- Thanks for the message, I am trying to connect to Cassandra using Spotfire(Its a visual analytics BI tool).

Comment: Also it would be of great help if you suggest which jdbc driver I need to use.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [cassandra-jdbc](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/), the connection URL will be something like this:

```
jdbc:cassandra://host1--host2--host3:9160/keyspace1?primarydc=DC1&backupdc=DC2&consistency=QUORUM"
```

But if you do not have to use JDBC, I recommend you the [DataStax Java-Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870502/how-to-connect-cassandra-using-java-class).
You will connect like this:

```
String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
String keyspace = "system";

Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
.addContactPoints(serverIP)
.build();

Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);
```

Comment: Hi Raphael- Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: jdbc:cassandra://host1--host2--host3:9160/keyspace1?primarydc=DC1&backupdc=DC2&consistency=QUORUM"  , In this i have the port, host details and keyspace details but not primarydc=DC1&backupdc=DC2&consistency=QUORUM". should i the same as it is?

Comment: You can just ignore and use `jdbc:cassandra://host1--host2--host3:9160/keyspace1`