# Cassandra throwing CodecNotFoundException [bigint <-> java.util.Date]

Tags: cassandra

I have a java entity that has a attribute of Date type and I have a database table which stores the date attribute to bigint cloumn but when I run the code it gives me this error:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [bigint <-> java.util.Date]

Can you please help me with the exception cassandra is throwing and solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

**You are inserting java.util.Date to bigint column, that's why you are getting this error.**

Use `getTime()` method to get times in milliseconds, which is long to inset into bigint column.

Example :

```
Date date = ; // you have the date
long timeInMilis = date.getTime();
```

Use `timeInMilis`  to insert into cassandra

or

you can change the column type bigint to timestamp, then you can insert `java.util.Date` directly, don't have to get times in milliseconds,

```
-------------------------------------
| CQL3 data type    |   Java type    |
|-------------------|----------------|
|     bigint        |    long        |
|-------------------|----------------|
|    timestamp      | java.util.Date |
--------------------------------------
```

More on CQL - Java Mapping : https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping

Comment: so you mean to say long type can be inserted in bigint column

Comment: Yes, Here is the more details http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that you are attempting to store a `java.util.Date` object in a  cql `bigint`.  The type that maps to `bigint` in the java driver is a `long` (see ['CQL to Java type mapping'](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping) section of the docs).

Assuming you mean to store the epoch milliseconds in this column you have a few options.

1. Change the column type to `timestamp` which maps to `java.util.Date` (and is set/accessed via `setTiemstamp`/`getTimstamp`).
2. Use [`setLong`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/SettableByIndexData.html#setLong-int-long-) in conjunction with [`Date.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) to convert the `Date` to a `long` representing epoch milliseconds.
3. Create and register a [custom codec](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/#implementing-and-using-custom-codecs) that maps `java.util.Date` to `bigint`, i.e.:

```java
import com.datastax.driver.core.*;

import java.util.Date;

public class CodecTest {

    static class DateToBigintCodec extends MappingCodec<Date, Long> {

        DateToBigintCodec() {
            // creates a mapping from bigint <-> Date.
            super(TypeCodec.bigint(), Date.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected Date deserialize(Long value) {
            return new Date(value);
        }

        @Override
        protected Long serialize(Date value) {
            return value.getTime();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TypeCodec<Date> codec = new DateToBigintCodec();
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
        try {
            // register custom codec
            cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry().register(codec);

            Date date = new Date();
            Session session = cluster.connect();
            // insert Date value into column v, which is a bigint.
            // schema:
            // CREATE TABLE simple.tbl (k int PRIMARY KEY, v bigint)
            PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare("insert into simple.tbl (k, v) values (?, ?)");
            BoundStatement bound = prepared.bind();
            bound.setInt("k", 0);
            bound.setTimestamp("v", date);
            session.execute(bound);

            // Retrieve column v as a Date.
            Row row = session.execute("select v from simple.tbl").one();
            System.out.println(row.getTimestamp("v"));
        } finally {
            cluster.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed you mention 'java entity', if that means you are using the mapping module, if you create the codec like I describe and register it before creating the Mapper, this will also work with the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tried and tested solution to this problem
Following is the code to insert or retrieve timestamp in Cassandra

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Timestamp timeStamp= Timestamp.valueOf(df.format(new Date()));

PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("SELECT id,time from keySpace.tableName where 
timestamp >=?  order by timestamp allow filtering");

BoundStatement bs = ps.bind(timeStamp);

ResultSet rs = session.execute(bs);

if (rs != null) {
    for (Row row : rs) {
    row.getTimestamp(time);
    row.getString(id);
}}
```

Note:- session.execute(bs), if you guys want to know from where this **session** came refer the following link
[How to connect Cassandra using Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870502/how-to-connect-cassandra-using-java-class)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16871984/9292502