# Cassandra exception com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException in gitlab pipeline

Tags: java, cassandra, gitlab

When i run this code in the gitlab pipeline its failing with NoHostAvailableException error. It works fine in my local. Can someone suggest me what should i do to make it work in pipeline?
One guess is to disable SSL maybe? How do i do that when i run it in gitlab pipeline?

```
     String serverIp = testConfig.get("serverIp");  
              String keyspace = testConfig.get("keyspace");
              String username = testConfig.get("username"); 
              String password = testConfig.get("password");
              
              String query = select * from bills where accountnumber='1234567'order by sequencenumber;
              
         
              SocketOptions so = new SocketOptions();
              so.setConnectTimeoutMillis(connectionTimeOut);
              so.setReadTimeoutMillis(readTimeOut);
                      
                     Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(serverIp).withPort(port).withCredentials(username, password).withSocketOptions(so).build();
                        
                     Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

 for (Row row : session.execute(query)) {
              
              billsequencenumber = row.getInt("sequencenumber"); 
              accountnumber = row.getString("accountnumber"); 
                                      
              }
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database and are you able to fetch values ?

Comment: Yes. I can do that from cassandra directly but not sure how to put it in the code and connect to cassandra database and run the query. Is there some instructions i can follow on how to connect it using the code?

Comment: Try to connect to the database and fetch the values, worry about `Rest Assured` later. See if this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16871984/3190953) helps

Comment: Getting below results.
[Row[144144141, 414141, 152, 1, B, C, 46, 2020-10-04, 2018-09-05, 33000-0110579227_238, 2020-08-04]]

How to read all values trying below but not working
ResultSet results = getSession().execute("Select * from test.table"); //getsession returns a session
int numcols = results.getColumnDefinitions().size();
for ( Row row : results ) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numcols; colIndex++) {
           System.out.println("data: " + row.getString(colIndex));
     }
}